# Existence of a holomorphic function in a neigbourhood

Tags: complex-analysis

Is there a holomorphic function $f$ such that
$$f(z)^3=z^3-1$$
in a neighbourhood of $z=1$? I think one should use facts about biholomophic functions.

Comment: See this similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1849558/holomorphic-branch-of-square-root-of-f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $f$ is such. First note that $f(1) = 0$. Now take the derivative of both sides of the equation.
$$ 3f^2(z)f'(z) = 3z^2 $$ This should be valid on a disk around $1$, especially at $1$. Plugging in $z=1$ however yields

$$0 = 3\cdot 0^2 \cdot f'(1) = 3.$$
Thus there's no such $f$.